# Lucene Scoring - How to score exact match better?

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I am using Lucene library. When searching for a term "**Table**", why does a document titled "**Tableware Set**" score better than document "**Blue Table**" although the latter one contains exact match. How to write query so that the latter one scores higher?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible, your analyzer (stemming) probably changes the "Tableware" to "Table", so lucene has no way of knowing what wasthe term before stemming...

Comment: @YossiVainshtein is right, have you looked at the suggestion here? [Search stem and exact words in Lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164879/search-stem-and-exact-words-in-lucene-4-4-0)